# jQuery datatables delete rows but only the ones which are dynamically added

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have followed this post(http://sebastiandahlgren.se/2013/07/27/adding-lines-to-table-with-jquery/) and implemented add row and delete row functionality in my jsp page.

Everything is working fine except one problem. The delete row button also deletes the row which were loaded during page load (say 30 rows).

Here is the code snippet

```
 function deleteRow () {
    if (count != 1) {
        $("table#myTable").dataTable().fnDeleteRow(count - 1);

        count--;
    }
  }
```

I only want to allow those rows which are dynamically added using the addrow function of datatables plugin. How can this issue be solved.

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle with the relevant code?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to distinguish between the pre-loaded rows and the ones that are added dynamically in your js code. A possible solution is to add a custom css class to the dynamically added rows only:

```
function addRow() {
    var table = $('table#myTable').dataTable();
    table.fnAddData( [
          '<input type="text" name="first_name_' + count + '">',
          '<input type="text" name="last_name_' + count + '">' ] );
    $(table._('tr')[count]).addClass('dynamicRow'); // add the dynamic css class

    count++;
 }
```

Then in the delete row method, check if the row css classes contain our dynamic one. If that is so, delete the row, otherwise do nothing. Here is the example:

```
function deleteRow () {
  if (count != 1) {
      var table = $("table#myTable").dataTable();
      if ($(table._('tr')[count - 1]).hasClass('dynamicRow')) {
          table.fnDeleteRow(count - 1);

          count--;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Sorry to say, but this would never work and produce errors to the console. You are mixing 1.10.x API with 1.9.x API methods on a `dataTable()` instance.

Comment: Do not be sorry at all - a mistake is a mistake. Actually I am glad you pointed that out, I think the current code should be fine with 1.9. Thanks

Comment: Good answer! Was misreading the article and got the impression that it was targeting 1.10.x, so have posted another answer, which is for 1.10.x only. But your updated answer is correct for 1.9.4.

Comment: Both the answers are clever.

Answer (score 2):

Edit : I misread the article, it is in fact using 1.9.4! But anyway - if you want to upgrade, which I would suggest, is here below the code from the article rewritten to take benefit of the powerful 1.10.x API. As @IvayloSlavov suggest, you could add a class to inserted rows. I would add an attribute to the row instead, like `<tr dynamic="true" ...></tr>`. Using the new API also have the advantage that dataTables controls like pagination is updated in the process (besides you get rid of the not-so-clever `count` variable :).

```
var row,
    table;

$(document).ready(function() {
    table = $('table#myTable').DataTable({
        filter: false,
        info: false,
        paginate: false,
        order: []
    });
    // Add initial row
    addRow();
});

function addRow() {
    row = table.row.add([
        '<input type="text" name="first_name_' + table.rows().data().length + '">',
        '<input type="text" name="last_name_' + table.rows().data().length + '">'
    ]).draw().node();
    $(row).attr('dynamic', true);
}

function deleteRow() {
    row = table.row(table.rows().data().length-1).node();
    if ($(row).is('[dynamic]')) {
        table.row(row).remove().draw();
    }
}
```

see demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/9rLv0uob/**

Comment: This js fiddle works but i am getting a table.row is null or not an object error on console. I have imported the following js   <script src="<%=request.getContextPath() %>/js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="<%=request.getContextPath() %>/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript"  src="<%=request.getContextPath() %>/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

Comment: Nice alternative, using an attribute. I'd recommend using a data- attribute, like `data-dynamic=true` or the like, as custom attributes may not be considered valid html.

Comment: @AbhishekSingh, have updated the fiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/9rLv0uob/ now using 1.10.2 and having some initial static rows (as you said you could have 30 rows on pageload). I dont know why, but for some reason, `table.rows().length` was a "feature" in 1.10.x, the correct usage is `table.rows().data().length`, so have updated it to using that.

Comment: @IvayloSlavov, you are absolutely right - to be true html5 compliant (validate in http://validator.w3.org/) custom attributes should be `data-xxx`.